Flutter text wrap with "/" character
I'm using Flutter to display a long text on mobile phone as following:
_1_&MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE27/xrMnX8uV6yF/LieGWSVEo0s+aVxCp8oYikEkEmha70jwA/CjMo+OKoy0f6OhBbqiuePVfNgTwoUmLELmVgw==

I placed it as Text string:
                   Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        longString ?? '',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

However, the screen size of the mobile may not width enough to show all the words in one line, it display as:
_1_&MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE27/
xrMnX8uV6yF/
LieGWSVEo0s+aVxCp8oYikEkEmha70jwA/
CjMo+OKoy0f6OhBbqiuePVfNgTwoUmLELmVgw==

But I expect the result should be:
_1_&MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE27/
xrMnX8uV6yF/LieGWSVEo0s+aVxCp8oYikEkEmha70j
wA/CjMo+OKoy0f6OhBbqiuePVfNgTwoUmLELmVgw==

Those "/" characters force the rest of the characters to the next line if do not have enough space. I do not want the auto new line with "/". What need to be added to get the expected result?

Replace / with encoded value

Well this has been an open issue in flutter. To basically allow text wrapping in an controlled manner.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61081
Here is the Workaround
Replace all "/" like:
.replaceAll("/","/\ufeff")
Insert ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE '\ufeff' between the characters you don't want to break. Same as the above but takes no space.
Text(                "_1_&MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE27/xrMnX8uV6yF/LieGWSVEo0s+aVxCp8oYikEkEmha70jwA/CjMo+OKoy0f6OhBbqiuePVfNgTwoUmLELmVgw==".replaceAll("/","/\ufeff"),
    
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),

Also added TextAlign.justify for format purposes.
